# I am trying to perform CURD Operation. But i am unable to do UPDATE operation. Please help me

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postman

I am trying to perform CRUD Operation by adding an image by passing a bearer token in authorization in header section in postman. But i am unable to do the UPDATE operation. There i am passing an image i don't want to update the image ,rest things i want to update. I passed all the fillable section in postman but i am getting error.

Error:Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: update `books` set `name` = ?, `author` = ?, `price` = ?, `quantity` = ?, `description` = ?, `books`.`updated_at` = 2021-07-04 17:39:47 where `id` = 1) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore-backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692

please help me to solve this.This is a screenshot of error in postman. Here is the screenshot of that error which i am getting.[image: screenshot]

If i put a dd($request) in the updateBook function then a separate error is coming but i am getting status 200 ok. Here is the screenshot of that error.[image: screenshot]

This is postman header section screenshot.[image: screenshot]
`FileController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileController extends Controller
{   
    //display books
    public function displayBooks()
    {
        $books=Books::all();
        return User::find($books->user_id=auth()->id())->books; 
    }
    //creating books
    function upload(Request $request){
        $book = new Books();
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->file=$request->file('file')->store('apiDocs');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();
        $book->save();
        return ["result"=>$book];       
    }
     //updating books
    public function updateBook(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book = Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            //dd($request->all());
            $book->price=$request->input('price');
            $book->name=$request->input('name');
            $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            $book->author=$request->input('author');
            $book->description=$request->input('description');
            
            $book->save();
            return[$book];
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Book is not available with this id'], 404);
        }
    }
}
```

`Books.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'file',
        'price',
        'name',
        'quantity',
        'description',
        'author'   
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

`Books_migration_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('file')->nullable();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share dd($request->all()) preview in postman

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MoolchandSharma...In preview i am getting an empty array(i.e. [])

Comment: Please Share Postman Headers Screenshot

Comment: @MoolchandSharma i have edited my post by adding the postman header section screenshot

Comment: `Column 'name' cannot be null`  - is there anything unclear about that error message? What have you tried to resolve it? Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - or is this question in any way really related to [tag:postman]?

Comment: Set two more headers in postman
accept -> application/json and contentType -> application/json and try again

Comment: Hello @MoolchandSharma i did this as u told me to do but it is still coming same error, 500 internal server error . Sql integrity constraints error.

Comment: Please share routes